# Used wordpress built-in permalink to change post url but the page is not found

Tags: permalinks

Used wordpress built-in permalink to change post url but the page is not found. I used the custom url option and appended /%postname%/ to it but it isn't working. What apart from this I have to change? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ensure that it's written to your .htaccess file in the root of your website.

If not, it didn't work when you saved it.

It should contain something like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```